# How to find out exactly what is transferred through my router?

Tags: router

I am on a quota-based internet where I am. I have a USB 3G modem that plugs into my TP-Link MR3420. My quota is being drained quickly, but only my wife and I connects to this router and during the day I am out at work. Wife is not a power user either she only uses Instagram, Facebook, Whatsapp, BBM, and some email and general browsing. Yesterday suddenly more than 1GB was drained when I wasnt home. I installed Data Usage app on our iPhones and none used that much. So either someone is stealing my internet or the ISP is cheating me. I looked through the Wifi connection list and didnt see anything suspicious.

What can I do to know exactly what goes between our devices, router, internet? I am hoping to find something that can tell me exactly which device connected to what server, up/download how many KB, and at what time.

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

To view the bandwith per device on the TPLink MR3420, login to the router and navigate to Wireless > Wireless Statistics.

The page will open to the right and it will show you what is connected to your router and how much each connection is sending and receiving.

**MAC Address** - the connected wireless station's MAC address

**Current Status** - the connected wireless station's running status, one of STA-AUTH / STA-ASSOC / STA-JOINED / WPA / WPA-PSK / WPA2 / WPA2-PSK / AP-UP / AP-DOWN / Disconnected

**Received Packets** - packets received by the station

**Sent Packets** -packets sent by the station
You cannot change any of the values on this page. To update this page and to show the current connected wireless stations, click on the Refresh button.

If the numbers of connected wireless stations go beyond one page, click the Next button to go to the next page and click the Previous button to return to the previous page.

Note: This page will be refreshed automatically every 5 seconds.
 [image]

note that the screenshot was taken using a simulator, so it does not show any clients.   Another way to check would be to look @ the DHCP leases.

I should mention that it is trivial to break the encryption on 99% of the encrypted WiFi signals out there.   I suggest changing your WiFi encyrption to WPA2 and use a good passphrase for the passkey.   If possible, disable WPS (the thing that lets you connect to the router by pressing a button).  WPS has many issues and can/will be used by an attacker looking to get on your WiFi.